# Trying to check if a number is greater than one

Tags: prolog

I am writing a piece of prolog code and i want to find out if a number is greater than 1.It always return false whenever i query it.

```
sss(count):- count > 1.
```

Answer (score 6):

Variables in Prolog begin with an uppercase letter or underscore. That being said,

`sss(Count):- Count > 1.`